# Save plot from matplotlib so that plot is centered

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot in Python using `matplotlib`. Specifically, I am using `contourf(Xm,Ym,Zm)` with `colorbar` and saving the plot using `figX.savefig('name')`, with `Xm,Ym,Zm` being some meshgrids.

With the colorbar next to the actual plot, the plot is off-center using default parameters in `savefig`.

How can I produce a figure so that the resulting image file is centered on the center of the actual plot. Best case scenario; the size adjusts so that colorbars and such wont be cut off.

I cant seem to find anything I can use in the parameters of `savefig()`, and simply have no idea how to go about this.

Some code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make data
Xm, Ym = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, 256), np.linspace(-3, 3, 256))
Zm = (1 - Xm/2 + Xm**5 + Ym**3) * np.exp(-Xm**2 - Ym**2)
levels = np.linspace(Zm.min(), Zm.max(), 7)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cp = ax.contourf(Xm, Ym, Zm, levels=levels)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cp)

#plt.show()

fig.savefig('plots/contour-plot.png')
```

The red cross should be equal to the purple cross:
[image]

Comment: The safest way is to define a [Gridspec width ratio](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec03.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-demo-gridspec03-py) with an invisible ax on the left side. Whether this is optically pleasing is another question.

Comment: Your plot is already centered — with respect to a horizontal axis.  If you want it centered wrt a vertical axis, use a horizontal colorbar.

Comment: I tried using a horizontal colorbar, however then it will be off center height-wise. I need it to be center center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can use [GridSpecs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec03.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-demo-gridspec03-py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

#generate data
import numpy as np
Xm, Ym = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, 256), np.linspace(-3, 3, 256))
Zm = (1 - Xm/2 + Xm**5 + Ym**3) * np.exp(-Xm**2 - Ym**2)
levels = np.linspace(Zm.min(), Zm.max(), 7)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
#define subplot width ratios 
gs = GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios=[1, 20, 1])

#leave first axis gs[0] empty for symmetry
#add middle plot for contour
plt_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
cp = plt_ax.contourf(Xm, Ym, Zm, levels=levels)

#add colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
cbar = fig.colorbar(cp, cax=cbar_ax)

#fig.savefig('test.png')

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

**Update**
As you now introduced the problem of different figure sizes: The same logic can be applied to the height of the colorbar by creating a [subGridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec). If we want to ensure consistency in appearance for different figure size ratios, we have to take this into account while creating the GridSpecs.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec, GridSpecFromSubplotSpec

#generate data
import numpy as np
Xm, Ym = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, 256), np.linspace(-3, 3, 256))
Zm = (1 - Xm/2 + Xm**5 + Ym**3) * np.exp(-Xm**2 - Ym**2)
levels = np.linspace(Zm.min(), Zm.max(), 7)

width = 20
height = 8
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
#define subplot width ratios 
gs_main = GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios=[1, 2*width, 1], wspace=1/width)

#add middle plot for contour
plt_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs_main[1])
cp = plt_ax.contourf(Xm, Ym, Zm, levels=levels)

#add colorbar to middle subGridSpec on the right
gs_cbar = GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 1, subplot_spec=gs_main[2], height_ratios=[1, 8, 1])
cbar_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs_cbar[1])
cbar = fig.colorbar(cp, cax=cbar_ax)

#fig.savefig('test.png')

plt.show()
```

This keeps the width of the colorbar, its distance from the main plot, and its relative height constant over a range of figure sizes.

Comment: Could it be, that adding a label to the colorbar complicates things? Even after applying all your suggestions, I cannot seem to get my use case to be centered. In the minimal example it works, but with more complex ones it does not. 

There are a few things that may be at fault: 
- removing labeling and tick labeling for main plot
- adding label to colorbar and formatting amonut of decimals
- setting aspect ratio for main plot 
- setting the figure size to scale with aspect ratio of main plot 

Do you happen to know which one of those could be the culprit?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would exclude tick label formatting and the colorbar y-label.

Comment: For now, I cant seem to find a solution for the more complex case, since your answer solves the minimal example, I will still mark it as solution. I have found another way of achieving what I wanted to achieve in the bigger picture.